# Can't upload project to pypi

Tags: python, anaconda, pypi

I'm trying to upload a project to PyPI, but I this command `setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest` fails:

```
 File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    setup(name='spongebot', version='1.0', packages=find_packages(), description = 'Upload a gif of Spongebob')
  File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 129, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\upload.py", line 63, in run
    self.upload_file(command, pyversion, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\upload.py", line 73, in upload_file
    raise AssertionError("unsupported schema " + schema)
AssertionError: unsupported schema
```

The `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='spongebot', 
    version='1.0', 
    packages=find_packages(), 
    description='Upload a gif of Spongebob',
)
```

Comment: Do you have a `~/.pypirc` file? Include contents here, removing passwords (if any).

Comment: yes I have it: [distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi

[pypi]
repository=https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
username=username
password=pasword

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `~/.pypirc` file, making sure to include the schema ("https"):

```
[distutils]
index-servers=
    pypi
    pypitest

[pypitest]
repository = https://test.pypi.org/legacy/
username = your.username

[pypi]
# repository = https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username = your.username
```

Comment: Doesn't work anyway :( Could be a problem of the name of ~/.pypirc?

Comment: Works for me.  I see you are using anaconda, maybe try it in a clean venv instead with latest version of setuptools installed?

Comment: How can I do it? I've always worked with anaconda, and I'm new on this.